# Linked lists: Assigning values to a node?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm not sure if I am even asking the right question (in reference to the question's title), but I am having trouble writing a statement that assigns the default values (in default) to the object pointed to by pNode? Thanks for any help anyone!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 50
struct book {
    char title[SIZE], author[SIZE], year[5];
};
typedef struct book Item;

typedef struct node {
    Item item;
    struct node * next;
} Node;
typedef Node * List;

int main(void){
    Node Node1, Node2;
    List pNode = &Node2;
    Item Default = { "title", "author", "1950" };
    //pNode -> Item = Default;???
    pNode -> next = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

The comment is my sad failure of a statement that I have come up with.

Comment: You clearly know how to access a member of a structure (you do so with `next` via `pNode->next  = NULL;`). The only trouble I see is the *potential* typo of using `Item` and not `item` for the member name (which we can't be *sure* is a typo or intentional, since you didn't specify what the actual *error* was; you should *always* include relevant, verbatim error messages with your questions).

Comment: it's `pNode->item = Default` as in lower case `item`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pNode -> Item = Default;
```

You need to change it to
pNode -> item = Default;

as the name of element is item, I(uppercase i)tem is name of your structure